# Import local file not resolved

Tags: typescript, electron, eslint, electron-forge

*(short story)*

I have two typescript files : `renderer.tsx` and `app.tsx`.

I want to import the later into the former, so I use :

```
import './app'
```

However, VS Code is complaining (actually I guess ESlint is complaining):

[image: error in VSCode]

What are prerequisites to remove this error ?

I have seen other project with exact same syntax without any problem.

*(long story)*

I want to learn how to build electron apps using typescript and react. I found [this guide](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react-with-typescript) in the electron-forge doc.

Following the guide works at runtime, but VS Code shows false error.

What I did :

```
yarn create electron-app my-app --template=typescript-webpack
cd my-app
yarn add react react-dom
yarn add --dev @types/react @types/react-dom
```

Created `src/app.tsx` file (in the same directory than the other file):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function render() {
  ReactDOM.render(<h2>Hello from React!</h2>, document.body);
}

render();
```

And added at the very end of the `renderer.tsx` file :

```
import './app'
```

Finally, added `"jsx": "react"` in `tsconfig.json`

Running `yarn start` works, the app starts as expected

This works well, the apps open.

But VS Code shows the error I mentionned above :( (`Unable to resolve path to module './app' .eslintimport/no-unresolved`)

how to fix ?

Full repro : https://github.com/stevebeauge/sosp-sp-tools

Comment: looks like you are importing a CSS file and that file(app.css) does not exist. if you are planning to use App.tsx file, you need to export it on App.tsx file and import it as a component.

Comment: if I refer to the previous line (part of the template), CSS files are imported using explicit extension. Why do you think import would try to import CSS file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is the proper way to solve my issue, but adding these lines in the `.eslintrc.json` file removed the issue :

```
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "node": {
      "extensions": [
        ".js",
        ".json",
        ".ts",
        ".tsx"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

(specifically the inclusion of `.tsx` in the extensions).

I guess it makes eslint try to handle theses extensions as module files.

Comment: wondering why css does not need to be specified here, because it has extension? so could import './app.tsx' work?

Comment: importing using `imports './app.tsx'` worked. I guess I could add css here, but I feel this should be reserved to code files (I'm beginner, I may be worng)

Comment: It's invalid in TypeScript to explicitly specify a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension in an `import` Statement.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: there's webpack working behind the scene. Maybe this has some impact ?